# localize existing iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I can't believe this hasn't been asked before (either I'm too unorganized in my coding practices or I didn't use the right keywords): How can I localize an existing iOS app that doesn't use NSLocalizedString (specifically just the first step, converting all strings literals to NSLocalizedString)?

I understand how the localization process works, but I don't want to change all texts myself. Surely there must be a tool that can convert `@"Hello World"` to `NSLocalizedString(@"Hello World", nil)`.

Sure I could do this manually with search and replace, but I can't believe there's no tool for this.

Comment: Write your own tool with perl/python/awk/etc, it's quite simple

Comment: @VitalyS.: That's exactly what I don't want to have to do.

Comment: Keep in mind that you probably have many string literals that shouldn't be localized. You may also find that you need to refactor some code to be properly localized. Automated tools for this will likely over localize your code.

Comment: @rmaddy: Ok, good point, but I would imagine a really good tool would help out here by listing all literals and letting me choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've wrote a xcode plugin to do this kind of job. Execute script is slow in xcode, so I did not choose to write s script to do it. Although writing Xcode plugin is kind of difficult, there is not official documentation, but after get used to it, it is fun to play with it.

Here is the link:

https://github.com/nanaimostudio/Xcode-Quick-Localization

Install:

1. Build the project use Xcode.

Usage:

1. Select multiple line, press Option+Shift+D
2. if no selection, it will convert only current line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Just needed to change the deployment target from 10.8 to 10.7 to run on my Mac. The shortcut "command + shift + c" didn't work for me, but the menu option did.

Comment: probably due to keyboard conflict? You can check it in Preference-> Key Bindings. And you can change the shortcut in QuickLocalization.m line 44. I've changed the deployment target to 10.7, thanks for the notice.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a conflict. Changed it to something else and it worked fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple `bash` script that searches for text

```
@"Your Text"
```

and replaces it with

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Your Text", nil);
```

They can be really powerful things